# Alamofire 4.0.0: [String:String] is not convertible to [String : Any] & Request is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, alamofire, swift3

I'm updating Alamofire to 4.0.0 Beta 1 and XCode 8 to Beta 6. First, I got  `[String:String] is not convertible to [String : Any]` error with this code

```
let parameter = [
        "scope":"\(scope)",
        "client": "\(clientId)"
    ]
Alamofire.request(link, withMethod: .POST, parameters: parameter, encoding: .json).responseJSON
```

and after I change add [String:Any] to parameter, the error gone but create new error : `Expression type 'Request' is ambiguous without more context`

```
let parameter:[String:Any] = [
        "scope":"\(scope)",
        "client": "\(clientId)"
    ]
```

Comment: The expected type of parameters in request method of Alamofire is [String: AnyObject]?. Could you change your parameter dictionary to type [String: AnyObject] and give a try ?

Comment: Since xcode 8 beta 6, all `AnyObject` change to `Any` @iamyogish

Comment: What it shows when you write it like 'let parameter : [String: String] = [
        "scope":"\(scope)",
        "client": "\(clientId)"
    ]'. Alamofire's parameters label expects string:string.

Comment: @AldoLazuardi could you open an issue on the GitHub project with your ambiguous issue? The more info you can provide the better. It's possible that's an actual bug that we haven't caught yet.

Comment: @cnoon Any reason why the methods why the methods were changed from .POST to .post in 4.0.0 ? Just curious :) Thanks.

Comment: They were modified to follow the new [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out methods are now lower case, so use `.post` instead of `.POST`

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1423

Answer (score 0):

replace the `.JSON` with `.JSONEncoding.default`